# how to get current PAM user in pam_ldap?

Tags: c++, c, pam

how can I get the user name that auth by pam_ldap in C/c++?
I found "pam_get_user" API, but how can I get the pam_handle_t for this function?

Thanks
Dma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the handle by calling:

```
int pam_start(const char *service_name, const char *user, 
              const struct pam_conv *pam_conversation, pam_handle_t **pamh);
```

`pamh` - is an output parameter in above api.

Check more details [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_start).

Comment: if I login through pam_ldap, how I can get current user info in a program? I don't know the paramater for pam_start.